# How to create local notifications with repeat interval as weekday?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to create a local notification with repeat interval as a weekday. For example, if I set notification for Monday and Friday for 5 pm, I want to repeat this notification every Monday and Friday at the same time, not on other days.

I have referred to this article but it's not complete: 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-send-local-notification-with-repeat-interval-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: does it work now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you can refer to this link completely, just modify the `notifyTime` and `repeateForMinute` inside，change the notifyTime to the date of Monday or Friday ,then change the repeateForMinute to seven days

for example,if the begin date is **2019/10/18 17:00 Friday**.you could change in the `LocalNotificationService` :

```
  public void LocalNotification(string title, string body, int id, DateTime notifyTime){    

        notifyTime = new DateTime(2019, 10, 18, 17, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);   
        long repeate7Days = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;    
        long totalMilliSeconds = (long)(notifyTime.ToUniversalTime() - _jan1st1970).TotalMilliseconds;    
        if (totalMilliSeconds < JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis()){    
            totalMilliSeconds = totalMilliSeconds + repeate7Days;    
        }    

         ...

        var alarmManager = GetAlarmManager();    
        alarmManager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, totalMilliSeconds, repeate7Days, pendingIntent);    
    }
```

you could download its [Source](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XamarinForms-Mvvm-How-to-834685b8) codes.

Comment: It will repeat only for a one week? or after every seven days? @LeoZhu

Comment: @Divyesh_008 every seven days.if you dont want it push notification,you could call cancel method.

Comment: I have that source code, but How I will get the date like notifyTime = new DateTime(2019, 10, 18, 17, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc); I want to set it as DateTime.now and after that. So the way you said, it is give a notification on every Friday of the week on time selected i.e. 5pm? and in iOS? @LeoZhu

Comment: @Divyesh_008 the nitifyTime is the date you want to give a notification,if you set as DateTime.Now,it will give a notification every 7 days at this time.(if DateTime.Now is Monday 2 pm,then it will give a notification every Monday 2pm) if you want it every Friday 's 5 pm,you should set it to a Friday and 5pm.

Comment: yes, i'm setting notification from today for friday 5pm than it will fire on that time, so how I will get the date of friday dynamically or i have to put manually? @LeoZhu

Comment: @Divyesh_008 If you are sure of the date you want to set, you can set it manually. or you could get DateTime.Now first,determine how many days off the date you want to set,then you add and subtract(e.g. if DateTime.Now you get is 2019/10/17 Thursday,a day from Friday,so you could set notifyTime 2019/10/18 17:00）

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200993/discussion-between-divyesh-008-and-leo-zhu-msft).